# Is PubNub able to handle concurrent publish messages from front (iOS/Android) and back end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

Is PubNub able to handle concurrent publish message from front (iOS/Android) and back end simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - PubNub can handle publishes to the same channel or multiple channels from multiple publishers from multiple regions with subscribers from multiple regions (in the world, that is). We have many customers that have this use case.

What is your specific use case?